# html links not working in 'Owl Carousel'

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

I'm trying to use Owl Carousel for the sliding carousel on the home page of my magento e-commerce website.

However the links I've wrapped the slides in aren't working or even clickable.

In another question, the poster fixed this and said :

*I figured it out finally!
I had a div that was on top and blocking out the links..
I just changed the z-index on that div and the links are now working.*

But I don't understand what exactly he has done. Could anyone pls help me on that? 
The part 1 of the slider is :

```
<div style="padding:29px 0 36px;background-color:#f4f4f4;">
<div class="container">
<div class="slider-with-side">
<div class="slider-area">
<div id="banner-slider-demo-8" class="owl-carousel owl-theme owl-bottom-narrow owl-banner-carousel">
<div class="item">
<a href="{{config path="web/unsecure/base_url"}}index.php/peripheriques/stockage.html"><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/porto/homepage/slider/08/slide2.jpg"}}" alt="" /></a>
<div class="content" style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;left:0;top:0;">
<div class="ribbon" style="position:absolute;text-align:right;">
<em style="font-weight:300;line-height:1;color:#fff;font-style:normal;">Vos Données En</em>
<h3 style="font-weight:700;line-height:1;color:#fff;">lieux</h3>
<h5 style="font-weight:600;line-height:1;color:#fff;">Sûr!</h5>
</div>
<div class="text-area" style="left:3%;bottom:15%;position:absolute;text-align:left;">
<h2 style="font-weight:600;line-height:1;color:#fff;background-color:#202020;background-color:rgba(23,23,23,.9);">SOLUTIONS <b style="font-weight:800;">DE STOCKAGE</b></h2><br/>
<p style="line-height:1.2;color:#fff;background-color:#444;background-color:rgba(23,23,23,.75);">Une offre vaste et polyvalente pour <b>STOCKEZ, <br/>PROTÉGEZ ET GÉREZ </b>efficacement vos données</p>
</div>              
</div>                      
</div>
```

part 2 is :

```
<div class="side-area">
<div class="item1">
<a href="{{config path="web/unsecure/base_url"}}index.php/consommables.html"><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/porto/homepage/slider/08/right-banner1.jpg"}}" alt="" /></a>
<div class="content">
<em  style="color:#fff;font-weight:400;font-style:italic;line-height:1;">Consommables</em>
<h2 style="color:#fff;font-weight:700;line-height:1;">& Fournitures</h2>
</div>
</div>
```

The slider layout has one big image in the left and 3 small ones in the right side. All have `<a href` tag and all are not clickable. When I view the page source the links are there !

Comment: Without code (html, css), or link, at least, nobody can't help, i am afraid...

Comment: You must provide a demo or show us some code.

Comment: I have just updated the question. My site is on a dev environment !

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how much this will help others who reach this page, but I had the same problem and none of the solutions I read online worked Here's how I solved the problem, and maybe you'll find this useful as well, even if the cause of the problem for you is something different.

First, I isolated the section with the owl carousel to see if it worked when it was the only thing on the page (it did). Then I added the header and footer and tested again (still worked). After that I added each section until the carousel links stopped working. Once I figured out which section was causing the problem, I pored over it to see if I could spot anything anomalous. In this case, there was a little scrap of code that was intended for a lightbox feature we decided to omit. Once that was removed everything worked fine.